# Why do some (usually, first ones) ordinal numbers seem completely different from corresponding cardinals?

Tags: etymology, comparative-linguistics

I've noticed that in some (all? most?) languages, ordinal for 1 and 2 are completely different (i.e., not derived) from corresponding cardinals:

English *One/Two/Three vs First/Second/Third* is a bad example, because "second" is a loanword; and in other German languages, only first one is different: Dutch: *Een -> eerst, twee - tweede*

Russian: *odin, dva, tri -> pervyi, vtoroy, tretiy*

Estonian: *üks, kaks, kolm -> esimene, teine, kolmas*

Has any research been done into it? I wonder what this condition could imply about proto-languages.

Comment: Not in Chinese (including most of its major varieties), nor in either of the Japanese ordinal systems. Korean has just one exception: the lexeme "1st" in its native ordinal system (첫 번째, not *한 번째); its Sino-Korean ordinal system is completely regular. Vietnamese has _thứ nhất_ rather than expected *_thứ một_ - suppletion of native system by the Sino-Viet system for "1st", and _thứ tư_ instead of *_thứ bốn_ for "4th".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question was indeed extensively studied in linguistic typology and a high level summary of results can be found in [WALS chapter 53](https://wals.info/chapter/53). It gives a good overview of possible systems of ordinal numbers (no ordinals at all, ordinals are the same as cardinals, ordinals are completely regular, special word for "first" only, special words for "first" and "second").

Languages with an independent word for "second" are concentrated in Europe and rare in other parts of the world.

Comment: I am so happy to learn about this resource!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

In Germanic language the word “other” (or a cognate) has often been used as an alternative for “second”, also in Dutch as can still be seen in the relic word “anderhalf” (for one and a half): there used to be a ordinal based system of “half cardinals” where “derdehalf = two and a half (literally the third half: 1/2 is just half, 1 1/2 the second half, 2 1/2 the third half etc.) The system is still used in West Frisian (Frysk)  e.g. “fjirdel” is just 3 1/2 (from “fjirde heal” = fourth half) and 1 1/2 is “oardel” also containing “oar” = other = second. Also Danish uses “anden” (other) as second and I believe it’s more common in Scandinavian languages. As you know in Dutch and in English also “third” is not regular, but does derive from “three” (“derde” in Dutch is a fossilised form of “drie + de” in a way). I think the low ordinals are used far more frequently than the higher ones and as such it’s well-known that higher frequency items are more prone to keeping irregularities that historically arose, because of easier learnability, in a way. So this way, the irregular lower ordinals have persisted.

Comment: »the word “other” (or a cognate) has often been used as an alternative for “second”,« well, *second* is a Romance word. I have read that *other* is **the** Germanic word for *second*, whilst *tweede, zweit-* in Dutch and German are new formations. »“derde” in Dutch is a fossilised form of “drie + de” in a way« Why fossilised? It looks like a metathesis to me but I don't see how it is fossilised.

Comment: @tobiornottobi because it hasn’t been replaced by the regularised “driede” ( which my kids do say sometimes) but because of its relative frequency the metathesised form “derde “ has been kept.

Comment: Okay, I'll have to think about your argument.

Comment: Cp. Ger. *viertel* "quarter" to "fjirdel", appearing regular among *x -tel*=1/x. Very interesting, thanks! Also for the interested reader, we say about wallclock time that it's either *drei-viertel* "three quarts" or *viertel vor* "quarter before/to" in an east-west isogloss. *ander* may compare to *anti*, *hinter* "behind", in weird ways, and we even say *gegen 6*, "to/towards/around 6" (viz *anti, against*, also *gen Italien* "to Italy"). *prim-* also compares to *pro*.

Comment: *anderthalb* is synonymous with *ein-ein-halb* (*one-an-half*) and their anlaut and ablaut are close enoug to latently lexicalize together. I hadn't figured out why it does not match though, and in fact I cannot accept "other half" quite yet. I wonder what *-dert* could mean and my closest match would be *dreh-* "turn", thus giving "a turn and a half". Since it's three halfs, the root of "tri" can fit, too. After all, another person (*ein anderer*) is the *third person*, and not strictly the one behind, though either fits 3rd-p.-perspective. *anders* "different"nagain fits "changed, turned".

Comment: @vectory *anderthalb* comes from older *anderhalb* (with inserted -t- for pronounciation) which literally means "second half", just like "anderer" is the second (i.e. other) person, not the third.. In Dutch two and a half used to be "derdehalf" and I would not be surpised if German also had something like "*dritterhalb", maybe still in some dialects?

Comment: I didn't doubt your evidence, I just suppose that it might obscure other tangents, to which the last comment doesn't add anything. It's plainly wrong, that "anderer" doesn't mean a third person. We all know what "other" means and its rather variable, now. The sense "other" is reconstructed much further back than the sense "second". It's an interesting word for sure. Also cp. "every other", Ger. "jeder zweite" vs "alle anderen".