# Language for which there is no suppletion for : first-one, premier-un. And the Hebrew case

Tags: hebrew, numbers, suppletion

Are there languages for which the word "first" is built with the word "one" ?
In many languages I know there exists a suppletion :

- English : first-one
- French : premier-un
- Latin : primus-unus
- Hebrew : ראשון-אחד

In Hebrew particularly, it is interesting that in the Bible one finds אחד with also a meaning of first : יום אחד (Gen 1), באחד לחודש (Deut 1).

So do you know languages for which there is no suppletion for 1-1st ?

And in particular do you know a theory for this particular suppletion, or any article about it ?

Thx

Comment: Note that the French example descends directly from the Latin one.

Comment: Would you count count (a) languages that have both a suppletive and a derived form (e.g., Irish _aonú_ ‘oneth’, _céad_ ‘first’), and (b) languages that don’t have morphological ordinals at all (e.g., Mandarin 一 _yī_ ‘one’, 第一 _dì yī_ ‘number one, first’)?

Comment: See also https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/30186/why-do-some-usually-first-ones-ordinal-numbers-seem-completely-different-from

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Barbiers (2007: '[Indefinite numerals one and many and the cause of ordinal suppletion](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024384106000659)', *Lingua* 117), suppletion between the cardinal and ordinal numerals of 1 is frequent, and he gives an explanation why *one* is special and incompatible with the standard derivation of ordinals (which I cannot explain in detail). He also gives references that may be interesting to you:

- Hurford, J., 1987. Language and Number. The Emergence of a Cognitive System. Blackwell, Oxford.
- Veselinova, L., 1998. Suppletion in the derivation of ordinal numerals. A case study. MITWPL 31.

But according to WALS, [feature 53A](https://wals.info/feature/53A#2/7.1/152.5), this is not a universal: 3 (out of 321) languages have ordinals 1/2/3 identical to cardinal numbers; 41 have regular derivation for these ordinals (among these Mandarin, on which see [Janus Bahs Jacquet's comment](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/37355/language-for-which-there-is-no-suppletion-for-first-one-premier-un-and-the-h#comment85442_37355)). I would add that Esperanto has a regular derivation as well, but that's cheating.

With regards to your Biblical Hebrew examples:

- The first (*yōm 'eḥād* "day one") also exists in English: *day*(/*bus*/*candidate*/*room*) *one*. I think we should analyse that as N-to-D raising of *day* and assume that *one* and *first* are allomorphs.
- The second (*bə'eḥād laḥodeš* "on one to-the-month") exists in Dutch: *op één november* ("on the first of November"). Marijke de Belder (2007: '[Silence and the Construct State in Dutch Date Expressions](https://www.academia.edu/download/3701290/03bel.pdf)', *Linguistics in the Netherlands 2007*) analyses this with a silent noun *dag* "day" and a construct state: *één <s>dag</s> november*, with the silent noun raised to D (explaining this ungrammaticality: *(*de) één november*). In this analysis it is the same as English *day one*, the only difference being that the noun is silent.

Comment: Notice that L. Veselinova is also co-author of the WALS article. She is a specialist on suppletion.

Comment: Yes, her publications list contains several items that may be of interest.